# Laravel and ajaxForm

Tags: php, ajax, forms, laravel

So I'm new to AJAX and I was trying this code

```
        <form role="form" id="ff" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="short"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputURL" placeholder="Paste a long URL..."></div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Shorten</button>
        </form>


<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#ff').ajaxForm({url: 'short', type: 'post'}, function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, I'm getting this error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

On my routes.php I have

```
Route::post('short', 'HomeController@ShortUrl');
```

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is thrown when you are not using the correct HTTP verb. Are you sure your route is `Route::post` ? I am sure that the route url is correct else it would throw a `HttpNotFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

It's likely not getting posted to the correct route.  Try naming it and letting Laravel figure out the route for you.

`Route::post('short', array('uses' => 'HomeController@ShortUrl', as => 'ajax.Short'));`

```
$('#ff').ajaxForm({url: '{{ URL::route("ajax.Short") }}', type: 'post'}, function() { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
});
```

If you aren't using Blade, change `{{ URL::route("ajax.Short") }}` to `<?php route('ajax.Short'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 

            $('#ff').$.post('short', {example_input_url: $('#exampleInputURL').val() }, function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

I have used the Jquery native function instead of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can URL::to

```
$('#ff').ajaxForm({url: "{{ URL::to('creation/store-company-info') }}", type: "POST"}, function() { 
alert("Thank you for your comment!");
```

});

If you use blade engine you can use  {{}} sign.Or use  if you are not use blade engine.